# how to return array using closure

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am new on Swift and I am trying to use closure for getting results back from viewcontroller

Here is the example

```
class MD5Calculator {

    static func imageChecksum(imageArray: [UIImage], onCalculated: @escaping () -> [String]){

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            var array: [String] = []

            for chosenImage in imageArray {
                if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 80) {
                    let checksum = jpegData.md5()
                    let chsum = checksum.toHexString()
                    array.append(chsum)
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //return array
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want md5 calculation do in background and when its done pass it to viewController.

I created closure but I don't know how to return it. 
my question is:

1. How to pass string array with closure
2. How to call ImageChecksum in view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of closure is not effective. The array you are about to send back should be the parameter of the closure not the returning type.

This should work

```
class MD5Calculator {

    static func imageChecksum(imageArray: [UIImage], onCalculated: @escaping ([String]) -> ()){

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            var array: [String] = []

            for chosenImage in imageArray {
                if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 80) {
                    let checksum = jpegData.md5()
                    let chsum = checksum.toHexString()
                    array.append(chsum)
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //return array
                onCalculated(array)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Use it in your ViewController like this

```
MD5Calculator.imageChecksum(imageArray: [imageArray]) { array in
    // 'array' is your returned result
}
```

Comment: how do I call on viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that you have defined closure incorrectly. Basically, the idea is, that you should define a closure with a return value, when you want to get the value **inside** the function, not the **outside**. The usage (in this case) would be something like: `let someConstant = onCalculated()`. **This is the way you get the value inside the function**.

In your case (you want to return a value from function), the closure should be defined something like: `onCalculated: @escaping (_ someArray: [String]) -> Void`. in this case, you would just return the value from the function: `onCalculated(someArray)`

The usage:

```
MD5Calculator.imageChecksum(
    imageArray: inputImageArray, 
    onCalculated: { someArray in
        // enter code here
    }
)
```

*P.S. Consider to use optional unwrap for closures!*

Answer (score 0):

You should send your result array as a parameter of closure, not as return value.

1. How to pass string array with closure?

   ```
   class MD5Calculator {

   static func imageChecksum(imageArray: [UIImage], onCalculated: @escaping (_ checksum: [String]) ->()){

       DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

           var array: [String] = []

           for chosenImage in imageArray {
               if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 80) {
                   let checksum = jpegData.md5()
                   let chsum = checksum.toHexString()
                   array.append(chsum)
               }
           }

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               //return array
               onCalculated(array)
           }
       }

   }
   }
   ```

2.How to call ImageChecksum in view controller

```
MD5Calculator.imageChecksum(imageArray: []) { (checksum) in

}
```